# Can I get greater granularity out of a MongoDB timestamp?

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, mongoose, precision, milliseconds

I'm getting a timestamp from my MongoDB database, but it's coming back with precision only in the seconds:

> Thu Jun 06 2013 16:15:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

I need greater granularity. Is there a way to get a MongoDB timestamp with precision in the milliseconds?

I'm making the call on my node.js server via mongoose:

```
var timestamp = new ObjectID().getTimestamp();
```

How can I get something more precise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ObjectIds are stored with the precision of seconds and you can't change it. So if you need something of millis granularity then you have to store your own timestamp value.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The reason why I'm using Mongo's timestamp is that I think my node host is running my server on two different machines, which means Date.now() in one request might actually be a greater time than in the next. Mongo was a way to centralize that time. Is there another centralized source that I could get a time with millisecond precision that isn't going to suffer from potentially have two different node servers?

Comment: I used a different way to get the same from mongod process. 
private Date getDBTime() {
       return (Date)db.eval("function(){ return new Date()}");
    }

Comment: db.eval("function(){ return new Date()}") throws an error saying "undefined is not a function". I'm getting db like this: var db = mongoose.connect(connectionString).connection.db; Does that look right so far?

Comment: This eval function is correct, you can directly run on mongo shell. May be moongoose syntax is different. Check the syntax for eval : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171764/server-side-sorting-using-mongoose-mongodb-node-js

Comment: Good call. I got it working (I needed to provide a callback), but it's still returning the same second-precision format. No millisecond granularity.

Comment: when ObjectId() is generated for new document, it is the CLIENT (i.e. driver) that generates it, not the server.

Comment: @MikePateras : Do a getTime() on that, which will print in millisecond  precision.

Comment: db.eval("return Date().getTime();", done); Like that? Still only getting seconds. @AsyKamasky Are you saying that I'm getting back the node server's time, not the database's time? I haven't noticed any timing issues using the Mongo timestamps, but I definitely have using the server's system time.

Comment: @MikePateras : I am really not sure why it is not giving your millis at your moongose client end, you can check this works in mongo shell ( and java which I use ). Also, what Asya meant was, new ObjectID().getTimestamp() will return the timestamp from the node server, not the db server

Answer (score 0):

I generated timestamps one after another and got these:

```
ObjectId("586a291570b9a181fc2f61ba").getTimestamp();
ISODate("2017-01-02T10:19:01Z")
```

For the next timestamp:

```
ObjectId("586a291570b9a181fc2f61bc").getTimestamp();
ISODate("2017-01-02T10:19:01Z")
```

You'll notice that although the only granularity printed by `getTimestamp()` is in seconds, there is a further granularity which causes the ObjectId string to vary even though both of them are at `01` second.

[The reason](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps):

```
BSON has a special timestamp type for internal MongoDB use and is not associated with the regular Date type. Timestamp values are a 64 bit value where:

    the first 32 bits are a time_t value (seconds since the Unix epoch)
    the second 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second.

Within a single mongod instance, timestamp values are always unique.
```

So the true granularity is in terms of the 32 bit ordinal generated by MongoDB. It is related to the `operations within a second`, and not to a time value, so you don't get it in terms of millisecond.